# Code First attribute for referring to a "user" by "author" in a "post" model

Tags: entity-framework

I have POCO models User and Post.
The post has an Author which really is a User, but I would like the Post model to refer to the user via the Author property.
I suspect I can tell EF that Author and AuthorId are really User and UserId with an attribute, the problem is that I don't know how.

**EDIT:**

Allow me to demonstrate.

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Author { get; set; }
}
```

I would like AuthorId to be the Id matching the User Id.

Comment: Go through [Fluent API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/14/ef-feature-ctp5-fluent-api-samples.aspx) and try to map your model.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use attribute for that. If you Inherit `Author` from User EF will do this all for you. And you don't need to have `authorId` in `author` class because It already have a uniqe Id (`UserId`).
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716779.aspx